# Iterate over list with sequence according to given dependencies from dict

Tags: python, iteration, sequence, graph-theory

I have a list `lst` and I want to iteratively transform each element in the list using a function `f`:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

def f(x):
    # do something
    return x
```

I can iteratively apply this transformation over the list:

```
new_lst = [f(x) for x in lst]
```

So far so good. Now we want to introduce sequencing for processing elements in the `lst`. The dict `ensure_transformed` describes a list of elements that need to be transformed before processing a given element:

```
ensure_transformed = {'a' : ['b', 'e'],
                      'b' : ['e', 'f'],
                      'c' : ['a', 'd'],
                      'd' : [],
                      'e' : [],
                      'f' : []
                      }
```

The interpretation is - Before transforming `a`, transform `b` and `e`, before transforming `b`, transform `e` and `f` and so on.

(The meaning of `'d' : []` is that no elements need to be processed before `d`. `g` is absent from `ensure_transformed` implying `g` shouldn't be transformed.)

How can I transform `lst` using function `f` while ensuring sequencing from `ensure_transformed`?

Options on the table:

1. Use recursion to go through list while keeping track of elements that have already been transformed. This approach has become messy to manage.
2. Re-order the list using the dict and then iterate over the list. I haven't tried this approach yet, but it seems promising.

I'm open to other approaches.

Comment: That sounds a lot like "tasks" that have a dependency graph. There are libraries to set up that kind of thing like [luigi](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html)

Comment: Is there a difference between `d` with empty list and `e' and `f`' not included at all?

Comment: Your option 2 is essentially a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)  of the dependency digraph. It is the natural way to go.

Comment: Starting with Python 3.9, there is [**graphlib.TopologicalSorter**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/graphlib.html) which can help with the topological sort.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Cool. I wasn't aware of that module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @CristianCiupitu in the comments, this is now very easy to do with Python 3.9 by using the [graphlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/graphlib.html#module-graphlib) module:

```
import graphlib
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

def f(x): return x.upper() #for example

ensure_transformed = {'a' : ['b', 'e'],
                      'b' : ['e', 'f'],
                      'c' : ['a', 'd'],
                      'd' : [],
                      'e' : [],
                      'f' : []
                      }

ts = graphlib.TopologicalSorter(ensure_transformed)

processed = [f(x) for x in ts.static_order()]
print(processed)
#prints ['E', 'F', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'C']
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ensure_transformed` dictionary describes a directed graph where `{'a': ['b', 'e']}` means that there is an edge `b → a` and an edge `e → a`.

Assuming that the graph has no cycles, your task is equivalent to applying [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) to it, for which you can find various algorithms.